# Google map pricing confusion from Web Application + Web Site

Tags: google-maps

We are creating a web application for a client that will be used to mark some proprietary data using google geocoding and google maps. It also has a public facing page that will allow any users to search this data and view on the map. Not all information is visible but the user can connect with the client to request full information. The end user is not charged any fee to see the map data

The same data will be used by internal employees to generate reports and do other analysis

Does it qualify for a free google map?

Apart from the map implementation the app has other modules (no maps), which are not visible to the public

We are only using client side scripting via the javascript v3 api. There is no server side calls to the maps api